# Options for In-Game Lodgement & Withdrawal Services from Payments Processors?

Tags: javascript, paypal, stripe-payments

I've seen a few questions on here about choosing between payment processors like PayPal and Stripe so I hope it's okay to post a non-code related question.

I'm developing an app and I'm wondering if there exists a payments processor that allows  players to lodge/transfer money into their game account (so that they'll have a real-money in-game balance), and allows them to withdraw/cash-out/transfer money out from their balance back to their bank or PayPal account instantly at any time.

I've seen such a thing happen on gambling/betting websites, but I haven't been able to find any clear information on this in PayPal and Stripe's product documents.

I'm wondering if there's a standard lodgement/withdrawal service, or would I need to approach each transaction as purchase transfer (player "purchases" in game curency from me when they lodge money, and I "purchase" their in game currency back from them when they choose to withdraw their money).

I've searched through PayPal and Stripe's documents but I can't seem to find an answer to my question. I'm planning to use Javascript and PHP to integrate the payments processor. Any advice on this would be really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given various gambling and money transmission laws this is an area you'll want to be pretty careful in.

It would be against the terms of service for Stripe: "Virtual currency that can be monetized, resold, or converted to physical or digital products and services or otherwise exit the virtual world."

With Paypal it would depend a bit on what your game is, from their acceptable use policy: "Activities involving gambling, gaming and/or any other activity with an entry fee and a prize, including, but not limited to casino games, sports betting, horse or greyhound racing, fantasy sports, lottery tickets, other ventures that facilitate gambling, games of skill (whether or not legally defined as gambling) and sweepstakes, if the operator and customers are located exclusively in jurisdictions where such activities are permitted by law."